# javascript unassigned default function parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, optional-parameters

In the following function:

```
foo = function(a){
    if (!a) a = "Some value";
    // something done with a
    return a;
}
```

When "a" is not declared I want to assign a default value for use in the rest of the function, although "a" is a parameter name and not declared as "var a", is it a private variable of this function? It does not seem to appear as a global var after execution of the function, is this a standard (i.e. consistent) possible use?

Comment: Any argument provided in the function signature is scoped to the function only. The function you have written as an example is correct.

Comment: A common short hand for this is, `return a || "Some value"` instead of `if(!a) a = "some value"; return a;`

Comment: better use `if(typeof a == "undefined")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a private variable within the function scope. it's 'invisible' to the global scope.
As for your code you better write like this

```
foo = function(a){
    if (typeof a == "undefined") a = "Some value";
    // something done with a
    return a;
}
```

Because `!a` can be true for `0`, an empty string `''` or just `null`.

Comment: Good point. `a = a || "some value"` has the same failings as `if(!a)`.

Comment: a will always be either an object or undefined, but yes point taken

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this context `a` has a scope inside the function.  You can even use it to override global variables for a local scope.   So for example, you could do `function ($){....}(JQuery);` so you know that `$` will always be a variable for the JQuery framework.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters always have private function scope.

```
var a = 'Hi';
foo = function(a) {
    if (!a) a = "Some value";
        // something done with a
        return a;
    };
console.log(a); // Logs 'Hi'
console.log('Bye'); // Logs 'Bye'
```